# big db for managing user files and settings

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm about to start a project that will hopefully eventually hit milion+ users. It is some kind of a site managment. Problem is how to set the db in MySQL? Some people suggest way 1 and others way 2. I hope you can help me decide the right path to start.

**needs to be stored:**

1. all users info:
   user | pass | account status
2. user files:
   path to compiled htm(in user folder with uid) | http
   request path | file seg1 | file seg2 | file seg3
3. user settings:
   personal settings (email..) | site settings (colors..) |

**my ideas to store the data are:**

1. path 1:
   have main db with table for usernames and passwords.
   create each user with db which inside has a table for user files and a table for user settings.
2. path 2:
   have main db for system which inside has:
   table for users and passwords and 2 more tables for each user: user_files, user_settings.

**edit**, add another path:

3. path 3:
   3 DB.. one for users\passwords second for user_files and third for user_settings. This way it would separate the rows' weight evenly between the user_files and user_settings. Is that true?

And would a flat file system without the DB (beside the user password) be a better option here?

thank you.

Comment: why do you believe a DB would be the way to go? why not flat files?

Comment: thank you for asking, my self i started building all the site in flat files except the user-pass table in mysql and it is working well, but people from my work said drupal works in DB and other big CMS companies work like that and its just a better and faster way to store and retrieve data instead of flat files. so im thinking about advancing before it gets big and cant change the structure. you think doing it all in flt files, settings as ini or split, and file segs in 1 file with split or 3 files seperated is better?

Comment: if your managers are forcing you to use DB then you have no other options. honestly i dont know what the best solution is, but these might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356851/database-vs-flat-files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499239/database-vs-flat-text-file-what-are-some-technical-reasons-for-choosing-one-ove

Comment: no managers here, its a side project im doing on my way home on the train every day (3hours total)...

Comment: just trying to figure out what way to go to not get stuck later if i pick the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first path is certainly the more conventional of the two, absent a compelling reason to break the system down into multiple schemas.  Something along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
  user_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  status_code INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE user_file (
  file_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  path VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
  INDEX (user_id),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES user(user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE user_settings (
  user_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(150),
  color VARCHAR(10),
  etc VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES user(user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
i was suggested a third path which i think would split the db better.

3 DB..
one for users\passwords
second for user_files
third for user_settings

that way it would separate the rows weight evenly between the user_files and user_settings.

is that true?

Comment: Three separate databases?  No, I wouldn't do that.  I would just use the three tables above in a single database.

Comment: Its not 3 tables, its (2xUsersCount)+1 tables. Is it still preffered?

Comment: Per-user tables?  So adding a new user means adding two new tables?

Comment: Yes each user needs a files table and a settings table

Comment: That is not even close to following to the relational model.  If you intend to implement this in MySQL, you certainly aren't going to want millions of tables, all but one of them with one record each.  You shouldn't have any issue with the three tables in my answer, each having millions of records each.

Comment: the userspasswods and userssettings i understand how to manage each in a table. i dont understand how to put all the users files in one table.. you will have for each user atleast 10 files. should i maybe make each user a table called "%userID%_files" and inside place the files of the user?

Comment: Each file gets a new record added to `user_file` table.  There's no issue with multiple users having files recorded in the same table, because each record has the user's unique ID number in it.